# Does std::atomic guarantee initialization initialization of types like int, float etc to 0/0.0?

Tags: c++11, initialization, stdatomic

Does `std::atomic<basic_type>` guarantee the value of `basic_type` to be 0 / 0.0 (whichever is applicable) when created as a class member without being explicitely initialized for:

- int / uint / short / ushort / etc...
- and; float / double

?

Example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    std::atomic<int> bar;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    return foo.bar; //foo.bar guaranteed to be 0?
}
```

Comment: I assume you have read [the fine manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic) and found it lacking. Is there some part of `no initialization takes place other than zero initialization of static and thread-local objects` that you find unclear? Basically, `std::atomic<int> bar` provides the same (few) guarantees of the initial value as `int bar` would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from cppreference documentation of [std::atomic default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic):

> The default constructor is trivial: no initialization takes place
>   other than zero initialization of static and thread-local objects.
>   std::atomic_init may be used to complete initialization.

Hence in your case you will have the same guarantees as if you had declared simply `int bar;`